# PHP Is it possible to send a cURL request from a specific country without proxies?

Tags: php, curl, country

I was wondering if it's possible to send a cURL Request from a specific country without using a proxy?

My problem is that everytime I send a request with cURL I get the language in the 'server language' which is 'dutch' because my hosting are in Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the language header as additional header?

```
$header = array();
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

I declared an array because you can set multiple headers like the user-agent etc...

Comment: Hi, I tried this already and it does not work. I think they detect the text out from the IP and then to country code? Have any ideas how to get around that? EDIT: This works on Facebook, but on the site I want it to work with it does NOT.

Comment: If they detect your position from your IP you need a proxy. Period. :-)

Comment: In my case I would need a proxy for every country then, which is 193 proxies I have to keep checking on to see if they work etc.. Not gonna do that.

Comment: I have a question (if you can answer)... What are you trying to do?

Comment: He is up to no good. Naturally it is un-ethical to help anybody asking such suspect questions.

Comment: I suspect that is trying to crawl something. I gave him a general advice. With no more infos I can't (and now I think I wouldn't) help.

Comment: Crawling is not necessarily bad. For examples search engines will crawl your site and you will not be angry towards them. Rather, you will fight to have a better SEO. But if you want to do something which you are ashamed of (come on, he is talking about hiding the country he is in, not only hiding his identity), then do not expect help. I am not talking about you, Napolux, I am just trying to tell the other people around that we would not be happy if a user would try to trick our service.

Comment: Wow calm down guys. I'm not trying to trick ur service or anything. Was just trying to get some offers from a website where you need to be in a specific country to get the offers the visitor normally have.

Comment: Love that chatgpt is here with us so that such condescending and know it all brats do not have control over which information a person can learn